# What kind of hero archetype is Rocky Balboa?

Tags: character, analysis, rocky, creed, rocky-balboa

I watched the Creed and Rocky films and I was wondering what kind of hero archetype (classic, anti, byronic) Rocky Balboa fits into.

I'm guessing it's probably classic/traditional hero since he has courage and strength. He's not an anti-hero or a Byronic hero, but there are a few moments where he shows that. So which hero archetype does Rocky fit?

Comment: Clearly he's an **underdog**.

Comment: Underdog being said, character complexity can not be described by a single archetypal word.

Answer (score 5):

I'd classify Balboa as an ["Everyman Hero"](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/common-hero-archetypes-in-literature#6-types-of-heroes-in-literature).  He doesn't really possess any great abilities, he's not even really that great of a fighter, but what he does possess is something he said to his son in the Balboa movie; the drive to keep getting up and keep moving forward when every enemy was beating him down.